# csv file is not defined to read a grph

Tags: python, csv

I create code to read a csv file.

the error message is

> File "C:/Users/amori/Desktop/programas de python/Nova
>   pasta/alg1.py", line 17, in get_data
>       csvFileReader = csv.reader(csvfile)
>
> NameError: name 'csvfile' is not defined

Can someone help me with this code? what I am doing wrong?

```html
import csv
import numpy as np
from sklearn.svm import SVR
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

dates = []
prices = []

def get_data(filename):
    with open(filename, 'r') as csvfile_:
        csvFileReader = csv.reader(csvfile)
        next(csvFileReader)
        for row in csvFileReader:
            dates.append(int(row[0].split('-')[0]))
            prices.append(float(row[1]))
        return
    
def predict_prices(dates, proces, x):
    dates = np.reshape(dates,(len(dates),1))
    
    svr_len = SVR(kernal = 'liner', c = 1e3)
    
    svr_poly = SVR(kernal = 'poly', c = 1e3, degree = 2)
    
    svr_rbf = SVR(kernal = 'rbf', c = 1e3, gamma = 0.1)
    
    svr_lin.fit(dates, prices)
    svr_ply.fit(dates, prices)
    svr_rbf.fit(dates, prices)
    
    plt.scatter(dates, prices, color='black', label='data')
    plt.plot(dates, svr_rbf.predict(dates), color='red', label='RBF model')
    plt.plot(dates, svr_lin.predict(dates), color='green', label='linear model')
    plt.plot(dates, svr_poly.predict(dates), color='blue', label='Polynomial model')
    plt.xlavell('date')
    plt.title('price')
    plt.title('support vector regression')
    plt.legend()
    plt.show()
    
    return svr_rbf.predict(x)[0], svr_lin.predict(x)[0], svr_poly.predict(x)[0]

get_data('aapl.csv')

predicted_price = predict_pice[dates, prices, 29]
    
print(predicted_price)
```

Comment: **@Pedro Amorim**, please once check your code and modify the question. You have file reading statement as `with open(filename, 'r') as csvfile_:` where file object is **csvfile_** but you're trying to use **csvfile** variable which is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

you have an underscore that's not wanted:

```
with open(filename, 'r') as csvfile_:
```

should be

```
with open(filename, 'r') as csvfile:
```